# How to find a default channel to send a starting message in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want my bot to find the first channel which is a text channel and which he has permission to send messages in. The problem is that I don't know how to check for permissions for each channel.

```
# When the bot is ready
@client.event
async def on_ready():

    # Ready message
    print("Bot is ready.")

    # Getting the default channel
    default_channel = checkChannels()


# Getting the default channel
@bot_has_permissions(send_messages=True)
def checkChannels():
    for guild in client.guilds:
            for channel in guild.channels:
                if str(channel.type) == "text":
                        return channel
```

Comment: You have to check this in the `for`-loop: `if channel.permissions_for(guild.me).send_messages:`

Answer (score 1):

You have few possibilities.

If you want to find the **system_channel** (Discord's welcome messages gets send here):

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        channel = guild.system_channel #getting system channel
        if channel.permissions_for(guild.me).send_messages: #making sure you have permissions
            await channel.send("I'm online!")
```

---

This way you will **find the first channel to which you have permissions**:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for channel in guild.text_channels: #getting only text channels
            if channel.permissions_for(guild.me).send_messages: #checking if you have permissions
                await channel.send("I'm online!")
                break #breaking so you won't send messages to multiple channels
```